# "Extra }, or forgotten $" and "Missing } inserted"

Tags: latex

I keep getting the same error in the `\end{align*}` line saying that "Extra }, or forgotten $" and "Missing } inserted" but I can't find any extra symbols nor do I think I missed any.

```latex
\begin{align*}
    (1^1 \x 1!) \x (2^2 \x 2!) \x (3^3 \x 3!) \x \hdots (k^k \x k!) \x \left[(k+1)^{k+1} \x (k+1)!\right] &= (k + 1)!^{k + 2}\\
    (k!)^{k+1} \x \left[(k+1)^{k+1} \x (k+1)!\right] \overset{I.H.}{&=} (k + 1)!^{k+1}\\
    (k!)^{k+1} \x k+1\left[(k+1)^k \x k!\right] &= (k!)^{k+1} (k+1)^{k+1}\\
    k+1\left[(k+1)^k \x k!\right] &= (k+1)^{k+1}\\
    (k+1)^k \x k! &= (k+1)^k\\
    (k!)^{k+1} &= k^k \x k!\\
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Try removing the trailing ```\\``` of your last line inside the `align*`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459629 - By the way, in case you don't a good answer here, try posting at https://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre] that shows all the necessary packages and how you defined your custom macros like `\x`

Comment: Removing the \\ in the last line of equation doesn't help.... im adjusting my code and try to write it in different ways (like adjusting the spaces etc.) but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must not hide the align marker `&` in an overset:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\x}{\times}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    (1^1 \x 1!) \x (2^2 \x 2!) \x (3^3 \x 3!) \x \hdots (k^k \x k!) \x \left[(k+1)^{k+1} \x (k+1)!\right] &= (k + 1)!^{k + 2}\\
    (k!)^{k+1} \x \left[(k+1)^{k+1} \x (k+1)!\right] &\overset{I.H.}{=} (k + 1)!^{k+1}\\
    (k!)^{k+1} \x k+1\left[(k+1)^k \x k!\right] &= (k!)^{k+1} (k+1)^{k+1}\\
    k+1\left[(k+1)^k \x k!\right] &= (k+1)^{k+1}\\
    (k+1)^k \x k! &= (k+1)^k\\
    (k!)^{k+1} &= k^k \x k!\\
\end{align*}




\end{document}
```

Comment: I fixed the error by doing as you said by myself but still, thank you for answering!